# Load single upright calligraphic symbol (pdflatex)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-fonts, eulervm

Thanks to the information gathered in this forum I am able to define specific math symbols using a different font than the one I chose (`eulervm`).

I am trying to apply the same reasoning to obtain an upright calligraphic symbol for `L` like the one from the font `mathpi` in addition to the calligraphic `L` from `eulervm`, as shown in the picture.
[image]

The only workaround I could come up with requires loading the additional package `newrxmath`, which is of course not a good idea since it clashes with `eulervm` and causes, for instance, the `\sum` symbol to disappear.
However, without it I have no way to access the character code for the upright calligraphic `L`.
I also tried using `mathscr` as an alternative, but it produces a very italic symbol that does not match the rest of my formulae.

Any suggestion, especially not involving the change of my base math and text fonts, would be very appreciated!

**Minimal "working" example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{altmathcal1}{OML}{mathpi}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\scrL}{\mathalpha}{altmathcal1}{'317}

\begin{document}

\xfonttable{OML}{mathpi}{m}{n}
$\mathcal{L} , \quad L , \quad \scrL , \quad \sum{t} $

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the script font from MathPi with the [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package, using the option `scr=mathpi`.

MathPi is a commercial font and I don't have it so I can't test an example, but here is one using a less oblique version of Boondox, which is similar to MathPi.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{L} , \quad L , \quad \mathscr{L} , \quad \sum{t} $
\end{document}
```

To get MathPi in place of Boondox, just replace `scr=boondoxo` with `scr=mathpi` and it should work.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!